# FindMinimum and logical constraints

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to find the minimum of a function. What I am working on is something like

```
FindMinimum[Norm[{u1, u2, u3}, 2] + Norm[{v1, v2, v3}, 2] + Norm[{p1, p2, p3}, 2], {u1, 0, 1}, {u2, 0, 1}, {u3, 0, 1}, {v1, 0, 1}, {v2, 0, 1}, {v3, 0,   1}, {p1, 0, 1}, {p2, 0, 1}, {p3, 0, 1}]
```

Now I want add the constraints:

```
{u1, u2, u3} + {v1, v2, v3} + {p1, p2, p3} = {somevec1, somevec2, somevec3}
```

and I want each of the 3 vectors to have at least 1 zero, and this is giving me trouble.

I tried `Count[{u1, u2, u3}, 0] > 1` and I'm getting this error

```
FindMinimum::eqineq: Constraints in {False} are not all equality or inequality constraints. With the exception of integer domain constraints for linear programming, domain constraints or constraints with Unequal (!=) are not supported. >>
```

**Edit:**

The current thing I have is:

```
w = {1, 1, 1};
FindMinimum[{Norm[{u1, u2, u3}, 2] + Norm[{v1, v2, v3}, 2] + Norm[{p1, p2, p3}, 2], {u1, u2, u3} + {v1, v2, v3} + {p1, p2, p3} == w && u3 == 0 && v1 == 0 && p2 == 0}, {u1, 0, 1}, {u2, 0, 1}, {u3, 0, 1}, {v1, 0, 1}, {v2, 0, 1}, {v3, 0, 1}, {p1, 0, 1}, {p2, 0, 1}, {p3, 0, 1}]
```

which is not general enough.

Comment: There is a dedicated StackExchange site for *Mathematica* now: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ -- please ask your future questions there.

Answer (score 0):

How about u1*u2*u3=0, ... etc.

Comment: ok I tried it but I get all zeros for solution w = {1, 1, 1};
FindMinimum[{Norm[{u1, u2, u3}, 2] + Norm[{v1, v2, v3}, 2] + 
   Norm[{p1, p2, p3}, 
    2], {u1, u2, u3} + {v1, v2, v3} + {p1, p2, p3} == w && 
   u1*u2*u3 == 0 && v1*v2*v3 == 0 && p1*p2*p3 == 0}, {u1, 0, 1}, {u2, 
  0, 1}, {u3, 0, 1}, {v1, 0, 1}, {v2, 0, 1}, {v3, 0, 1}, {p1, 0, 
  1}, {p2, 0, 1}, {p3, 0, 1}]

Comment: That's a flaw of the Mathematica's FindMin algo probably. You can try better seeding the algorithm, or why not find the exact solution by manually solving it?

Comment: Because I want to scale it for many dimensions and perhaps different number of non-zeros. I'll try setting an initial point.